# Connection Reset by peer: mod_fcgid:

Tags: php, apache, mod-fcgid

When I try to run a program in PHP using domPHP API to create PDF files in runtime - with Godaddy server, I am getting the message - Connection Reset by peer: mod_fcgid

the same work in our local server as well as in Dreamhost and Host gator.

Godaddy support insists that this is a coding error and not server issue.
Can any one help me?

thank You

Sathish

Answer (score 0):

[set_time_limit()](http://www.php.net/set_time_limit)